# Get "No such file" exception in sftp outbound-gateway after upgrade spring integration version from 4.3.12 to 5.2.5

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

After we upgrade spring integration version from 4.3.12 to 5.2.5, the new exception occurred as follows：

> org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [bean 'ollSrFeedbackDeliver$child.ollSrFeedbackOutboundGateway.handler' for component 'ollSrFeedbackDeliver$child.ollSrFeedbackOutboundGateway'; defined in: 'class path resource [config/olltms/olltms_srFeedback_context.xml]'; from source: ''int-sftp:outbound-gateway' with id='ollSrFeedbackOutboundGateway'']; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to execute on session; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: failed to rename from /out/DCS_SR_FEEDBACK/SVR3oBweZKH7sf5Lf1Szlef-20200618211747550.xml to /out/DCS_SR_FEEDBACK/backup/SVR3oBweZKH7sf5Lf1Szlef-20200618211747550.xml; nested exception is 2: No such file

our config as follows:

```
    <int-sftp:inbound-streaming-channel-adapter id="ollSrFeedbackInboundAdapter"
                                            comparator="sftpFileModifiedTimeComparator"
                                            session-factory="cachingSftpSessionFactory"
                                            channel="ollSrFeedbackInputChannel"
                                            filename-pattern="${filename-pattern}"
                                            remote-file-separator="/"
                                            remote-directory="${sr-feedback-remote-directory}">
        <int:poller fixed-delay="${sftp-in-fixed-delay}"/>
</int-sftp:inbound-streaming-channel-adapter>
```

use outbound gateway to move file to backup folder:

```
        <int-sftp:outbound-gateway session-factory="cachingSftpSessionFactory"
                               id="ollSrFeedbackOutboundGateway"
                               command="mv"
                               expression="headers.file_remoteDirectory+'/'+headers.file_remoteFile"
                               rename-expression="headers.file_remoteDirectory+'/backup/'+headers.file_remoteFile"
    />
```

Before the upgrade, everything is running normally, and problems occurred after the upgrade. After check jsch log, find:

```
DEBUG [task-scheduler-2] SftpSession: - File: /out/DCS_SR_FEEDBACK/SVR3oBweZKH7sf5Lf1Szlef-20200618211747550.xml was successfully renamed to /out/DCS_SR_FEEDBACK/backup/SVR3oBweZKH7sf5Lf1Szlef-20200618211747550.xml
DEBUG [task-scheduler-3] SftpSession: - Initial File rename failed, possibly because file already exists. Will attempt to delete file: /out/DCS_SR_FEEDBACK/backup/SVR3oBweZKH7sf5Lf1Szlef-20200618211747550.xml and execute rename again.
DEBUG [task-scheduler-3] SftpSession: - Delete file: /out/DCS_SR_FEEDBACK/backup/SVR3oBweZKH7sf5Lf1Szlef-20200618211747550.xml succeeded. Will attempt rename again
```

is there anything change after upgrade ?

Comment: Any chances to have a simple project to let us to reproduce the problem? Are you sure that `/out/DCS_SR_FEEDBACK/SVR3oBweZKH7sf5Lf1Szlef-20200618211747550.xml` exists when you try to rename it?

Comment: I am sure this file exists. But after getting the exception, we cannot find the file neither in folder "/out/DCS_SR_FEEDBACK" nor "/out/DCS_SR_FEEDBACK/backup". The file is lost.